# Tikz: Log ticks and minor ticks in x-axis

Tags: latex

I have a figure  representing y=f(x) and I want to plot it for values of x in the range [10, 300] in log scale using tikz. If I set xmax=1e3 the ticks and minor ticks are as expected. However, when I set xmax=300 the minor ticks dissapear. In the two pictures below I show this behaviour:

```
\begin{axis}[
legend cell align={left},
legend entries={{Test},{Test Clip},{Train},{Train Clip}},
legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)}, anchor=north west, draw=white!80.0!black},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
xlabel={$\dim(z)$},
xminorticks=true,
xmode=log,
xmin=10, xmax=1e3,
y grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
ylabel={PSNR},
ymin=15.8800682154579, ymax=26.0503182019626
]
```

[image]

```
\begin{axis}[
legend cell align={left},
legend entries={{Test},{Test Clip},{Train},{Train Clip}},
legend style={at={(0.03,0.97)}, anchor=north west, draw=white!80.0!black},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
xlabel={$\dim(z)$},
xminorticks=true,
xmode=log,
xmin=10, xmax=300,
y grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
ylabel={PSNR},
ymin=15.8800682154579, ymax=26.0503182019626
]
```

[image]
As you can see the only thing I change is the parameter xmax.

Thank you in advance